# How to make any column hyperlinked in dynamic gridview , where that hyperlink column is linked to another gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to make any column hyperlinked (except first one) in dynamic gridview , where that hyperlink column is linked to another gridview.

This dynamic table shows two type of output as mentioned below:

View 1:

```
Start       Bus_no  Change_at       Change_Bus_no   Destination     Means
Desu Office 715     Hanuman Mandir  781             Subroto Park    DTC
Desu Office 715     Palam Airport   764             Subroto Park    DTC
Desu Office 715     Palam Airport   781             Subroto Park    DTC
```

View 2:

```
Start           bus_no  Destination             Means
Subroto Park    764     Nehru Place Terminal    DTC
```

In first view I want to make column 2nd (Bus_no) and 4th(Changed_Bus_no) and in second view I want to make column 2nd as hyperlink column which will be linked to another grid view table.

Gridview Code is given below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
          BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
          GridLines="Vertical" ForeColor="Black">

          <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
          <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
          <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
          <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
          <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
          <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
          <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
          <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
          <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
      </asp:GridView>
```

please help. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Template Field for your requirement.

Try like this,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
      BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
      GridLines="Vertical" ForeColor="Black">

      <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
      <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
      <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
      <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
      <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
      <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
      <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
      <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Column">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblthird0" runat="server" Text="items" />
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField> 
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Second Column">
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#Gridview2"></asp:HyperLink>
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>      
         </Columns>      
  </asp:GridView>
```

You can do like this for all your columns.

Comment: thanx for your reply. but I can not fix any column this grid view is dynamic. please suggest me another solution.